# How to configure hyper-v on windows 8 for windows phone app development in windows 8, without windows 8 proffestional

Tags: windows, mobile

I have to develop windows 8 when I'm opening new project with windows phone app, I am getting
[image: error windows]

error and when I am running the program I'm getting [image: this error]

actually I am having windows 8 but not professional, can any body help with how to configure Hyper-V when not windows 8 Professional , so now I am confused about what to do and where I can configure,.

Comment: according to MS you need Windows 8 Pro to run Hyper-V So your only option is to upgrade.

Comment: oh are you sure there is not alternative, i read links in MS too for that..........

Comment: As far as I know, in order to run the Emulator, you need Hyper-v, in order to run Hyper-V under Windows 8, you need The pro version. I think you can still do development with the SDKs, but you would need to test on a real phone, as opposed to the emulator.

Comment: so, there is no alternative ?

Comment: Yes as far as I can tell your options are upgrade or use a phone to do the debugging.  But right now(1/23/12) windows 8 pro upgrade is  $39.99US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, this is sad story with emulator for windows 8 - take a look at this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx

Windows Phone 8 Emulator
Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)

When your computer and BIOS settings are already configured to support Hyper-V, the setup program for the SDK enables and starts Hyper-V. If you are already a local administrator on the computer, setup also adds you to the Hyper-V Administrators group. Otherwise you may have to enable these requirements manually.
Requirement
How to check and enable this requirement
Hyper-V must be installed.
See How to enable Hyper-V for the Windows Phone Emulator.
Hyper-V must be running.
Check the status of the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service in the Services snap-in.
For more information about managing services, see the following topics:
Start, stop, pause, resume, or restart a service
Configure how a service is started

Its not easy to fulfill all this requirements ...

Comment: i have read that and confused and not getting proper answer. i have already read this particular link, confusing me lot

Comment: I think you got it: you write "actually I am having windows 8 but not professional" and the proper answer is "Windows 8 Pro edition or greater requires". Or am I wrong?